# React Native - Button Styling Issues

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, styling, react-props

I'm confused as to why my button doesn't seem to resemble the default native react button with a square shape that spans to the max width of the viewport - I've researched and understand from the react docs that the native button is very limited in terms of styling and props, but mine seems to be missing the default styling - any tips? My button component can be found [here](https://github.com/markohanesian/docket/blob/master/components/addTodo.js)

I've tried adding backgroundColor to the styles, color, etc. but nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this... customise further as you required
you will love react-native and to style after this :)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

export default function AddTodo({ submitHandler }) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const changeHandler = (val) => {
    setText(val);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="add a game to the docket..."
        placeholderTextColor="white"
        onChangeText={changeHandler}
        clearTextOnFocus="true"
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={() => submitHandler(text)}>
        <Text style={styles.btnText}>add game</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    paddingVertical: 6,
    backgroundColor: "#2DCCCF",
    flexDirection: "row",
    color: "white",
  },
  btn: {
    height: 45,
    borderRadius: 8,
    elevation: 3,
    backgroundColor: "#AB47BC",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  btnText: {
    color: "#fff",
  },
});
```